# Json encode with utf8_encode displaying the unknown characters

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, utf-8

I am using the infinite scroll to get the latest posts from the database in codeigniter framework. When I am sending the data from the function its not displaying the actual Hindi string that I have saved in the database.

I have also used the UTF-8 character encoding in page.

Here is my code:

```
 public function getNextPosts() {        
 foreach ($post as $result) {
         $postdata = '';
         $postdata .='<div class="post_content">
         इस धरा पर ही नहीं सम्पूर्ण ब्रहामंड में जो कुछ भी है यह सब मिटने वाला है जो भी पैदा हुआ है
         <a href="javascript:void(0);">अधिक पढ़ें</a></div>';

         $postdata .='<div class="post_content">
         हालाँकि जहाँ तक आत्मा की बात है उस विषय में हमें स्पष्ट हो जाना चाहिए
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">अधिक पढ़ें</a></div>';
    }
           header("Content-Type: application/json");
            $data = array('result' => $postsdata);
            $data_result = array_map('utf8_decode', $data);
            echo json_encode($data_result);
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('div#posts_data').infinitescroll({

    nextSelector: "div.navigation .alignleft a",
    navSelector: "div.navigation",
    contentSelector: "#posts_data",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
}, function(response) {
    var jsonData = response.result;
    $container= $("div#posts_data");
    $theCntr.append(jsonData);
});
```

Output:

```
<div class="post_content">???? ?? ????????? ?? ????? ?????? ???? ??? ???? ??? ???? ??, ?? ????? ???? ?? ???? ?? ?????? ???, ???? ???? ??????? ???? ?????, ????? ???? ?? ????? ?? ????? ???, ???? ??????????? ?? ???????????? ?? ????? ???. ????? ????? ???? ?? ???? ??......<a href="javascript:void(0);">???? ?????</a></div>

<div class="post_content">???? ?? ????????? ?? ????? ?????? ???? ??? ???? ??? ???? ??, ?? ????? ???? ?? ???? ?? ?????? ???, ???? ???? ??????? ???? ?????, ????? ???? ?? ????? ?? ????? ???, ???? ??????????? ?? ???????????? ?? ????? ???. ????? ????? ???? ?? ???? ??......<a href="javascript:void(0);">???? ?????</a></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing this line: `$data_result = array_map('utf8_decode', $data);`? I think `json_encode` does the encoding job for you! (:

Comment: `utf-8` doesn't support Hindi language characters [see](http://www.unicode.org/standard/supported.html)

Comment: Thanks @ i am using array_map() function to avoid null values.

Comment: Try one of `UTF-16` character set